# How can I point a subdomain to amazon web services and configure aws for handling requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a domain purcharsed on www.wix.com . I would like to set up a subdomain for pointing to a web app hosted on Amazon Web Services Elastic-Beanstalk.
I've already configured a CNAME Record **subdomain.domain.com => My AWS Public DNS.** (Wix Domain Settings)

It still not appearing the website on *subdomain.domain.com*

What would be the next step to make it work ?

Comment: How long has it been since you created the CNAME record? It can take several hours for a new record to propagate.

Comment: When you run `nslookup subdomain.domain.com` does it come back with the information from your new CNAME record?

Comment: @MarkB
`
Server:  127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find subdomain.domain.com: NXDOMAIN
`

Comment: Did you actually replace `subdomain.domain.com` in that command with your real subdomain name you just created a CNAME record for?

Comment: Yes, I did. Should I setup something on AWS side ? (I've tried creating virtual hosts but still not working)

Comment: "I've tried creating virtual hosts but still not working" I don't know what that means exactly. You have a endpoint URL assigned by Elastic Beanstalk right? And you created a CNAME that points to that correct? But your computer can't find that subdomain DNS record yet. So you just need to wait a while longer. Until your computer sees the DNS record you aren't even getting to the point where AWS comes into the picture. Try again in 6 hours.

Comment: You might look up how to do a "DNS flush" on your computer to see if that gets the subdomain to start resolving. The instructions will be specific to your operating system.

Comment: To eliminate local DNS caching issues, try a DNS lookup from http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php

Comment: The CNAME is pointing to my Amazon Instance's Public DNS... Should I change to the web app Url (example:  myapp.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com ) ?

Comment: The output of nslookup now is:  http://pastebin.com/E1dR4RA2

Comment: Point the CNAME to your Elastic Beanstalk's web app URL (myapp.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com), not to the EC2 instance. After you make this change, you'll have to wait for the DNS change to propogate based on the entry's Time-to-live (TTL).

Comment: It worked. Really thank you. How can I mark it as the answer?